# proving inequality involving the minimum function is non-negative

Tags: algebra-precalculus

for $a,b,c,d \in [0,1]$ and b>a, and also d>c, how can I show that:
$$
\min(b,d) - \min(a,d) -\min(b,c) +\min(a,c) \ge 0
$$

We clearly have that $\min(b,d) - \min(a,d)\ge 0$ since the min function is non-decreasing in its arguments.

But then we also have that :
$\min(a,c) - \min(b,c) \le0$

So what information do I need to conclude that the first term is at least as big as the second term in absolute terms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $b$ and $c$ cannot be the two largest elements among $a,b,c,d$ and similarly $a$ and $d$ cannot be the largest two elements among $a,b,c,d$. It follows that both $\{b,c\}$ and $\{a,d\}$ contain one of the two smallest elements from $a,b,c,d$ and therefore $\min(b,c) + \min(a,d)$ is the sum of the two smallest elements of $a,b,c,d$. It follows that $\min(b,d) + \min(a,c)$, being the sum of two elements of $\{a,b,c,d\}$, is at least this value.